# A Hibernate web application to make use of multiple tables in single database?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an web application where it uses multiple tables in single database.

How do i configure to make use of those multiple tables in single database.?

Multiple hibernate configuration file is good enough or Programmatically configuring to use one table in single DB.

I thought of taking Single HibernateUtility file where it contains

```
 public class HibernateUtility {

    public static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(String url, String user, String pass, String dialect,
            String driverclass) {
        try {

            AnnotationConfiguration conf = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
            // <!-- Database connection settings -->
            conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
            conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", user);
            conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", pass);
            conf.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", dialect);
            conf.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverclass);
            return conf.buildSessionFactory();

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Log exception!
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(String url, String user, String pass, String dialect,
            String driverclass) {
        return buildSessionFactory(url, user, pass, dialect, driverclass);
    }

    public static void shutdown(String url, String user, String pass, String dialect, String driverclass) {
        getSessionFactory(url, user, pass, dialect, driverclass).close();
    }

}
```

`AnnotationConfiguration` class is deprecated what other class is to be used ?

But i have a doubt here where do i configure Entity classes ?

Comment: You are using multiple tables in single database and want to know how to use multiple tables in single database? :)

Comment: yes. With out any concurrency issues.